# Jquery append same items again and again

Tags: jquery, append

When i open main page(in this [URL](http://e.yazilimsozluk.com/Home/Index) ) it has 4 items in list and then i click another link(in footer i click contact)  and in contact page when i click main page again (in footer places link)
it again append items
how can i clear previous items?

this is my main page code

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

                $.getJSON('http://xx1', function (data) {

                    $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {

                        if (marker.PlaceExtra3 === '1') {

                            $("#listeu").append("<li data-role='list-divider' role='heading' class='ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count' style='text-align:center'> <a href='http://localhost:65028/Home/KonuDetail/ " + marker.PlaceID + "' </a> " + marker.PlaceExtra2 + " - " + marker.PlaceName + " </li>");
                            $("#listeu li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                            $(".ui-btn-inner:eq(0)").css("background", 'red');
....
```

Comment: I don't see the issue you are describing. What is duplicated? What items are you trying to remove?

Comment: I've been looking at it for 2 minutes and I can't figure out what you're describing. I don't see anything being duplicated...

Comment: Please consider providing a simplified test case on jsfiddle.net or a similar service, as the provided URL may or may not exist for future readers of this question. Thank you.

Comment: in chrome and firefox browser it duplicitated and also it is style getting bad

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to clear your list.

```
$.getJSON('http://xx1', function (data) {
    // empty list before the loop to clear the list
    $("#listeu").empty();
    // list is now empty, continue as normal
    $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
    if (marker.PlaceExtra3 === '1') {
        $("#listeu").append("<li data-role='list-divider' role='heading' class='ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count' style='text-align:center'> <a href='http://localhost:65028/Home/KonuDetail/ " + marker.PlaceID + "' </a> " + marker.PlaceExtra2 + " - " + marker.PlaceName + " </li>");
        $("#listeu li:last").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".ui-btn-inner:eq(0)").css("background", 'red');
```

Comment: i added it but it still has problem

Comment: this links work(http://e.yazilimsozluk.com/Home/Index)  but in footer i click contact and then in footer i click places to return same page(http://e.yazilimsozluk.com/Home/Index) and it still append and duplicate

Comment: I'm not seeing the same behavior at http://e.yazilimsozluk.com/Home/Index (I'm using Chrome). Also, for what it's worth, in my example above I put the `.empty()` calls within the `$.getJSON` success function. You put them before the call to `$.getJSON` on your page. It shouldn't make a difference as the `$.getJSON` call only happens once (on `document.ready`). Clicking "Contact" and then clicking "Places" shouldn't make a difference because they are two separate URLs.

Comment: yes they ayre differen URLs but why it cause problem?are there any solution to prove page reload? i move all my file to another host (http://teknonova.com/Map)  but the problem is same...in default there is list for places and it is work but when i click contact and in contact page again i click places it s style getting bad and also  it append same items...

Comment: in this picture you can see damaged css...i just click links : http://e.yazilimsozluk.com/untitled.png